# How to make the console window invisible in batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How to make an invisible cmd.exe window for my batch application.

Answer (score 0):

This will open a window for a full second then restart itself hidden...

```
@echo off

if %1'==Hidden' goto code
powershell "saps -filepath %0 -ArgumentList Hidden -WindowStyle Hidden" >nul 2>&1
exit /b


:code
```